# Get comma separated list of column values based on value in another column

Tags: bash, awk

I want to get a comma-separated list of all of the values in certain columns (2,4,5) based on the value in column 1 of a tab-delimited file.

I was working with adapting the command below, but instead it is going to give me a list of all the values in the column, not just the one for each person - and I'm not sure how to do that.

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $2}' $i | sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/'
```

This is what I am working with

```
Bob     24      M       apples  red
Bob     12      M       apples  green
Linda   56      F       apples  red
Linda   102     F       bananas yellow
```

And this is what I would like to get (I want to keep duplicates and the order)

```
Bob     24,12   M       apples,apples   red,green
Linda   56,102  F       apples,bananas  red,yellow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- for duplicate names the gender will always be the same otherwise save the 'last' one seen

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
      {   nums[$1] = nums[$1]   sep[$1] $2
        gender[$1] = $3
        fruits[$1] = fruits[$1] sep[$1] $4
        colors[$1] = colors[$1] sep[$1] $5
           sep[$1] = ","
      }
END   { # PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"      # this line requires GNU awk
        for (name in nums)
            print name,nums[name],gender[name],fruits[name],colors[name]
      }
' input.tsv
```

This generates:

```
Bob     24,12   M       apples,apples   red,green
Linda   56,102  F       apples,bananas  red,yellow
```

**NOTE:** this just happens to display the output in Name order; if ordering (by Name) needs to be guaranteed OP can run the output through `sort` or if using `GNU awk` then uncomment the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` line

Answer (score 1):

You never need sed when you're using awk.

Assuming your key values (first fields) are grouped as shown in your example (if not then sort the file first) then without reading the whole file into memory and for any number of input fields (you just have to identify which field numbers don't accumulate values, i.e. fields 1 and 3 in this case) you can do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
$1 != vals[1] {
    if ( NR>1 ) {
        prt()
    }
    delete vals
}
{
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        pre = ( (i in vals) && (i !~ /^[13]$/) ? vals[i] "," : "" )
        vals[i] = pre $i
    }
}
END { prt() }

function prt(    i) {
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        printf "%s%s", vals[i], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Bob     24,12   M       apples,apples   red,green
Linda   56,102  F       apples,bananas  red,yellow
```